# I am getting the following error for my code, please help

Tags: equations

Code:

```
$$x(t) = 
\left[ \begin{array}{c}
i_{L1}(t)\\
i_{L2}(t)\\
v_{C1}(t)\\
v_{C2}(t)\\
i_l(t)
\end{array}\right]
$$
Recall that the input voltage $V_g$ is an independent voltage source and the load impedence is $Z_l = R_l + sL_l$. Apparently, the load is short-circuited by $S_2$ in Mode 1.\\
The circuit equations in Mode 1 can be written in the state space form $K\cdot x = A_1\cdot x + B_1\cdot u$, that is,

$$\left[ \begin{array}{ccccc}
L_1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & L_2 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & C_1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & C_2 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & L_l
end{array}\right] \frac{d}{dt} \left[ \begin{array}{c}
i_{L1}(t)\\
i_{L2}(t)\\
v_{C1}(t)\\
v_{C2}(t)\\
i_l(t)
\end{array}\right] = \left[ \begin{array}{ccccc}
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
-1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -R_l
\end{array}\right] \left[ \begin{array}{c}
i_{L1}(t)\\
i_{L2}(t)\\
v_{C1}(t)\\
v_{C2}(t)\\
i_l(t)
\end{array}\right]$$
```

Error:

```
! Extra \right.
l.25 end{array}\right]
                       \frac{d}{dt} \left[ \begin{array}{c}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: See also [Why is $$ not recommended](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to?s=1|1.7144) please

Comment: You missed back slash: `end{array}`.

Comment: Got if folks. missing '\'

Answer (score 3):

It's easier to set the matrices with package `amsmath`. This also improves the horizontal spacing. Things like the missing `\` or not using `$$` are already covered by the question comments.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\[
  x(t) = 
  \begin{bmatrix}
    i_{L1}(t)\\
    i_{L2}(t)\\
    v_{C1}(t)\\
    v_{C2}(t)\\  
    i_l(t)
  \end{bmatrix}
\]
Recall that the input voltage $V_g$ is an independent voltage source and the
load impedence is $Z_l = R_l + sL_l$. Apparently, the load is
short-circuited by $S_2$ in Mode~1.\\
The circuit equations in Mode~1 can be written in the state space form
$K\cdot x = A_1\cdot x + B_1\cdot u$, that is,
%
\[
  \begin{bmatrix}
    L_1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
    0 & L_2 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & C_1 & 0 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & 0 & C_2 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & L_l
  \end{bmatrix}
  \frac{d}{dt}
  \begin{bmatrix}
    i_{L1}(t)\\
    i_{L2}(t)\\ 
    v_{C1}(t)\\ 
    v_{C2}(t)\\ 
    i_l(t) 
  \end{bmatrix}
  =
  \begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
    -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
    0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -R_l
  \end{bmatrix}
  \begin{bmatrix}
    i_{L1}(t)\\  
    i_{L2}(t)\\  
    v_{C1}(t)\\  
    v_{C2}(t)\\  
    i_l(t)
  \end{bmatrix}
\]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]